# SQL server 2008 are prevented form being installed on Windows 7 - error message "access is denied "

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008

I have recently installed Windows 7 enterprise . When I try to Install Microsoft SQL server 2008 EXPRESS edition , I get an error message : "Access is denied" just right after the installation process begins . I looked and found workarounds in Internet relevant to missing access rights but unfortunately these were not suitable to my case  .I have also checked the User rights assignment/debug programs with no result. Can you please advice having also in mind that I have been classified as administrator  ?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have UAC enabled and did not start the installation via "Run as Administrator". In that case your user, despite being a member of the Administrators group, has only normal user privileges.